# I’m new to coding in VHDL and don’t understand why my code will not show an output when simulating on a VWF file

Tags: vhdl

My code will not simulate an output when running the VWF file.

I have tried changing the code several different time and don't really understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
            library IEEE;
            use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
            use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

            entity Counter_JM is
            Port (    
                up_down : in std_logic;
                    LED : out std_logic;
                Q   : Buffer integer Range 0 to 7);

            end Counter_JM;

            architecture archi of Counter_JM is

            Begin

                -- up/down counter
                process (up_down)
                begin
                    if (Q=7) then
                        Q<=0;   
                    end if;

                    if (up_down = '1') then
                        Q <= Q + 1; 
                    else   
                        Q<=0;           
                    end if;

                    if (Q=0 or Q=1) then
                        LED <= '0';
                    else 
                        LED <= '1';
                    end if;

                end process;    
            end archi;
```

The LED output should show high for 4 cycles and low for 2 on the VWF file

Comment: Your entity is named as "counter" and you have "up" and "down", however you have no clock..... I suggest you look on the www for some VHDL counter code examples.

Comment: Please look at this link, this should get you started - https://startingelectronics.org/software/VHDL-CPLD-course/tut19-up-down-counter/

Comment: Does up_down go up and down?

Comment: Thank you for the link, I have looked into and was able to find a way to make it work! As I said I am still extremely new to Vhdl and the learning curve is a bit high. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you use up_down. But as Oldfart said, you don't have a clock. I have simplified and modified your code (it works for me (in modelsim):

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity Counter_JM is
     Port (   
            clk: in std_logic;
            up_down : in std_logic;
            LED : out std_logic
                );
end Counter_JM;

architecture archi of Counter_JM is


Begin

process (clk)


    variable Q: integer range 0 to 7;

begin

    if rising_edge(clk) then
        -- up/down counter     

        Q := Q + 1;

    if Q=1 or Q=2 then
        LED <= '0';
    else
        LED <= '1';
    end if;

    if Q = 7 then
        Q := 0;
    end if;

    end if;

end process;    

 end archi;
```

and also created/generated a simple testbench [here](https://vhdl.lapinoo.net/testbench/)  :

```
`-- Testbench automatically generated online
-- at http://vhdl.lapinoo.net
-- Generation date : 7.6.2019 11:22:53 GMT

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tb_Counter_JM is
end tb_Counter_JM;

architecture tb of tb_Counter_JM is

    component Counter_JM
        port (clk     : in std_logic;
              up_down : in std_logic;
              LED     : out std_logic);
    end component;

    signal clk     : std_logic;
    signal up_down : std_logic;
    signal LED     : std_logic;

    constant TbPeriod : time := 1000 ns; -- EDIT Put right period here
    signal TbClock : std_logic := '0';
    signal TbSimEnded : std_logic := '0';

begin

    dut : Counter_JM
    port map (clk     => clk,
              up_down => up_down,
              LED     => LED);

    -- Clock generation
    TbClock <= not TbClock after TbPeriod/2 when TbSimEnded /= '1' else '0';

    -- EDIT: Check that clk is really your main clock signal
    clk <= TbClock;

    stimuli : process
    begin
        -- EDIT Adapt initialization as needed
        up_down <= '0';

        -- EDIT Add stimuli here
        wait for 100 * TbPeriod;

        -- Stop the clock and hence terminate the simulation
        TbSimEnded <= '1';
        wait;
    end process;

end tb;

-- Configuration block below is required by some simulators. Usually no need to edit.

configuration cfg_tb_Counter_JM of tb_Counter_JM is
    for tb
    end for;
end cfg_tb_Counter_JM;`
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this code I will look it over as study materials to see what I can learn from it.

Comment: No problem, the forum is there to help each other. It might be easy if you mark this answer as "best answer". Then everyone knows that this question has been answered for you.